# How can I get all Pokemons with height, weight in rtk toolkit query in Browser

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, pokeapi

I'm working with Redux Toolkit Query and React, and I want to display all Pokémon in the browser, not just one.

Can someone show me how to implement the exact endpoints and frontend for this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding a second endpoint that queries the pokeAPI for specific pokemon by name.

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

const pokemonApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "pokemonApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/"
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemon: builder.query({
      query: () => "/pokemon",
      transformResponse: (response) => response.results
    }),
    getPokemonByName: builder.query({
      query: (name) => `/pokemon/${name}`
    })
  })
});

export const { useGetPokemonQuery, useGetPokemonByNameQuery } = pokemonApi;
export default pokemonApi;
```

Update the `PokemonCard` component to consume a `name` prop and make the `useGetPokemonByNameQuery` query to get and render a specific pokemon.

```
import { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } from "./pokemonApi.slice";

function PokemonCard({ name, url }) {
  const {
    data,
    error,
    isLoading,
    isError,
    isSuccess
  } = useGetPokemonByNameQuery(name);

  return (
    <ul>
      {isLoading && "...Loading..."}
      {isError && error.message}
      {isSuccess && (
        <div>
          <h2>{data.name}</h2>
          <p>Experience: {data.base_experience}</p>
          <p>Height: {data.height}</p>
          <p>Weight: {data.weight}</p>
          <img alt="sprite front default" src={data.sprites?.front_default} />
        </div>
      )}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default PokemonCard;
```

Move the `useGetPokemonQuery` hook call higher up the ReactTree and map a list to the `PokemonCard` component.

```
export default function App() {
  const { data, error, isLoading, isError, isSuccess } = useGetPokemonQuery();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Pokemon</h1>
      {isLoading && "...Loading..."}
      {isError && error.message}
      <ul>
        {isSuccess &&
          data.map((pokemon) => (
            <li key={pokemon.name}>
              <PokemonCard {...pokemon} />
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-get-all-pokemons-with-height-weight-in-rtk-toolkit-query-in-browser]

[image]